# Обращение к *.dll (Delphi) из под C# проекта

Tags: c#, delphi, dll

Есть DLL написанная на Delphi.

```
type
  TReceiveData = procedure(PBuf: Pointer; const Size: LongWord) of object; 
  TResultCode  = (rcOK, rcErrorCore, rcErrorUsed, rcErrorInit, rcErrorParams, rcErrorUnits);

Functions 
  function Init(const AIP: PChar; AReceive: TReceiveData): TResultCode;
```

При обращении к ней через C# выдает ошибку.
Код C# ниже

```
[DllImport("Sensor.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern TResultCode Init(uint const_IP_dev, block_cb_fn dev_resive_data);
```

```
private void btnInit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
            var arr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            adr = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetAddressBytes().Length; i++)
            {
                adr = adr << 8 | arr.GetAddressBytes()[i];
            }
            lbGet.Text = NativeMethods.Init(adr, FCallback).ToString();
   }
```

```
private static readonly block_cb_fn FCallback = new block_cb_fn(MethodAvailable);
```

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public unsafe delegate int block_cb_fn(TReceiveData* ptr);
```

```
public unsafe struct TReceiveData
    {
        public byte* PBuf;
        public long Size;    
    }
```

Ошибку выдает следующую
Помощник по отладке управляемого кода "PInvokeStackImbalance" : "Вызов функции PInvoke "VektorTDS!VektorTDS.classes.NativeMethods::Init" разбалансировал стек. Вероятно, это вызвано тем, что управляемая сигнатура PInvoke не совпадает с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой. Убедитесь, что соглашение о вызовах и параметры сигнатуры PInvoke совпадают с неуправляемой целевой сигнатурой."

Куда копать, или что не правильно?

Comment: Если dll 32-x разрядная, то в Delphi  соглашение о вызовах по умолчанию не `stdcall`, a `register`. `procedure of object`  - методы объекта, имеет скрытый параметр, и в dll вообще-то такие функции  обычно не используют

Comment: `TReceiveData` - это, если я не ошибаюсь, [**TMethod**](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TMethod), подробнее про это можно почитать [здесь](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TObject.MethodAddress). Соответственно у процедуры `TReceiveData` есть дополнительный скрытый параметр (первый): `Self: TObject`.

Comment: 1. Импортируемая функция в вашем случае должна возвращать какой-нибудь из общеизвестных типов например integer.
2. Вы подключаете её как stdcall, а в дельфях она такая же?
3. Ну и есть сомнения что метод of object может быть так легко передан. Вы ранее подобное делали? Есть рабочие варианты?